# "In welcher Situation" versus "In welche Situation"

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

For example:

> In *welcher* Situation benuzt man Dativ?
>
> In *welche* Situation benutzt man Akkusativ?

What is the correct form of *welch-* here and when do we use it with which case?

The issue is with the preposition *in*, which can be used with the dative or the accusative case, depending on the context.

Comment: Does this answer your quesiton: [When to decline welche?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33217/when-to-decline-welche)

Comment: The case of *welch-* depends on the preposition, in this case *in*, which is a [Wechselpräposition](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/wechselpr%c3%a4positionen). If the linked topic does not help you, please update your question to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: The issue is with the preposition ' in ' which can both be used with the dative and accusative cases depending on the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accusative vs Dative: "Schau in der/die Schublade!"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40282/accusative-vs-dative-schau-in-der-die-schublade)

Comment: The question of in + dative vs accusative is also discussed here: [When do we use prepositions “in der” and “in dem”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/when-do-we-use-prepositions-in-der-and-in-dem/22000#22000)

Comment: I didn't find any of the comments particularly useful in answering the OPs question despite generally knowing when to use the dative or accusative declinations! However, experimenting with Google Translate (German to English) makes it clear that welche in the situation given will take a dative ending.